# Change <span> to <div> if it contains this text Jquery

Tags: jquery, function, replace

I need to change a span to a div across the whole site.

I have a span which is

```
<span style="font-size: 85%;">You are here: [breadcrumb]</span>
```

I need this to be

```
<div style="font-size: 85%;">You are here: [breadcrumb]</div>
```

I tried this

```
$("span")
.filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'You are here:'; })
.replaceWith(function() { return "<div>" + this.innerHTML + "</div>"; });
```

But it did not work..
Can anyone assist please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is almost correct. The issue is because you're using an exact match in the `filter()` function, yet I assume that the `[breadcrumb]` text is dynamic. To fix this use `indexOf()` to find elements where the text begins with the expected value:

```js
$("span")
  .filter((i, el) => el.textContent.indexOf('You are here:') === 0)
  .replaceWith(function() { return `<div>${this.textContent}</div>`; });
```

```css
div { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size: 85%;">You are here: [breadcrumb]</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be simply like this?

```
$("span")
.replaceWith(function() { return "<div>" + this.innerHTML + "</div>"; });
```

Comment: This replaces all `span` elements, not the one matching the required text though

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `each` and check the condition if required text present in `span` then replace it with div as shown in below example

```js
$(function(){
  $('span').each(function(){
     var text = $(this).text();
     if(text.indexOf('You are here:')>=0) {
     $(this).replaceWith('<div>' + text + ' - thi is div </div>');
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="font-size: 85%;">You are here: [breadcrumb]</span>
<span style="font-size: 85%;">You are not here: [breadcrumb]</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($('span').text = 'You are here:'){
    $('span').remove();
    $( "<div><b>hello</b></div>" ).appendTo( "body" );
  }
```

```js
 if($('span').text = 'You are here:'){
    $('span').remove();
    $( "<div><b>hello</b></div>" ).appendTo( "body" );
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>You are here:</span>
```